# error while sorting using multiple android studio

Tags: java, android

I searched many stackoverflow issues on this error. Many are related to android. I could not use those answers to fix this. I'm getting this below error:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:623)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:578)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.BuildException: Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:529)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.doFullTaskAction(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:253)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:813)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.invokeAaptForSplit(LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask.java:507)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\YOUNES\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\YOUNES\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ -D \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.quizuno.app -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractAapt.link(AbstractAapt.java:34)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:809)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\YOUNES\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe with arguments {package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\YOUNES\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar -M \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug -m -J \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\generated\source\r\debug -F C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\resources-debug.ap_ -D \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\manifest_keep.txt --custom-package com.quizuno.app -0 apk --output-text-symbols \\?\C:\Users\YOUNES\Downloads\codecanyon-21213145-quizix-android-quiz-app-with-admob-fcm-push-notification-offline-data-caching\QuizixV2.0_Android_files\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug --no-version-vectors}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:78)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AbstractProcessExecutionAapt$1.onSuccess(AbstractProcessExecutionAapt.java:74)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1237)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:911)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:822)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.set(AbstractFuture.java:664)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture.set(SettableFuture.java:48)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessExecutor$1.run(GradleProcessExecutor.java:58)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\YOUNES\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:389)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
    ... 9
```

Comment: The problem is from your resource file. Check everything inside the `res` directory. Also check your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Update your compileSdkVersion to 28